# custom pie chart colors in nvd3-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I'm trying to customise pie chart's colors using [`angular-nvd3`](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) extension.

This is what I caught in [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0lrJY2VfpUh5n2YB8zsL?p=preview). As you can see the color of the legend was being customised but the chart wasn't.

I need the colors being passed inside the data object.
Do you have any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize color in pie chart of NVD3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191542/how-to-customize-color-in-pie-chart-of-nvd3)

Comment: but how can it be reached according to this angular solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that hard, try this -

```
$scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 500,
                ...
                ... // You code
                ...
                color:['#C620D2','#528BE8','#45B29D']
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks this was a real help. On a deadline too.