# How to change nvd3 chart fill & stroke colors through CSS

Tags: html, css, pie-chart, sugarcrm, nvd3.js

I am trying to adjust the colors of nvd3 charts through CSS in SugarCRM. The pie chart colors are declared a bit differently than the other nvd3 charts so I am stuck on how to change them through CSS. Below is a snippet of the html of an nvd3 bar chart with the working CSS. Then there is a snippet of the html of an nvd3 pie chart.

**Bar chart html:**

```html
<g class="nv-group nv-series-0" fill="#1f77b4" stroke="#1f77b4" style="stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1;">
```

CSS to adjust the color of the bar chart:

```css
         .nv-group.nv-series-0 {
            fill: #2A6EBB;
            stroke: #2A6EBB;
        }
```

**Pie chart html:**

```html
< g class="nv-slice nv-series-0">
<path d="M1.055492460015125e-14,-172.375A172.375,172.375 0 1,1 -97.2397105173445,142.32912324434182L0,0Z" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180); stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 3px; stroke-opacity: 1;">
```

The colors of the pie chart are declared inside the style attribute in a path tag so I am not sure how to change them through CSS. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked this [question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191542/how-to-customize-color-in-pie-chart-of-nvd3)

Comment: @shabeer90 Thanks, I have. Unfortunately this is in SugarCRM so I do not have access to the function and need to make the adjustment through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<g stroke="#98df8a" fill="#98df8a" class="nv-slice">
```

Check it on nvd3 website the color(fill) is in g element.

anyways 
here is css for your html

```
g.nv-slice > path{
    fill: #2A6EBB;
    stroke: #2A6EBB;
}
```

if you want to select n'th element

```
g.nv-slice:nth-child(n) > path{
    fill: #2A6EBB;
    stroke: #2A6EBB;
}
```