# How to change the font colour inside the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I have created a pie chart with the following code. I get the result for that, but I need a small favour.

```
<html lang="en">

<body>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
</head>

<div id="billplan"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-   js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var billplanchart = dc.pieChart("#billplan");


d3.csv("data/billplanchart.csv", function(error, experiments) {

var ndx           = crossfilter(experiments),
   planrate        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.plan_amount;}),
 billplandimgroup    = planrate.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return   (Math.round(d.Count));});

 billplanchart
 .width(240)
 .height(80)
 .dimension(planrate)
 .group(billplandimgroup)
 .slicesCap(5)
 .innerRadius(10)
         .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#FFDA33","#05BCDC","#EA7262","#0071CF","#58A531","#E51F30"]))

.legend(dc.legend())

.on('pretransition', function(chart2) {
    chart2.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
        return  Math.round(dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100)*10)/10+ '%';
    })
});

billplanchart.render();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this chart as a result. 
[image]

Now please tell me how to change the font color of the numbers in percentage to `black`.

Comment: share snippet code please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191542/how-to-customize-color-in-pie-chart-of-nvd3

Comment: Just put `color: black` to your font selector.

Comment: where is your proper code?

Comment: I have added my full code in the question itself, there is nothing more to that.